# Could not Import Pandas: TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to use the following pandas, but could not import it at all.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/releases/download/v0.15.0/pandas-0.15.0.win-amd64-py2.7.exe

However I could not import it:

```
import pandas as pd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\api.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.io.gbq import read_gbq
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\gbq.py", line 39, in <module>
    if LooseVersion(_GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_VERSION >= '1.2.0'):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\version.py", line 265, in __init__
    self.parse(vstring)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\version.py", line 274, in parse
    self.component_re.split(vstring))
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

What's wrong guys?

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happened to me when upgrading google-api-python-client to a version higher than 1.2.0.
The problem is in Pandas, but it has been fixed: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/403f38da35ab04d3997f61db3c98134fe02910d3

The solutions is to either downgrade google-api-python-client, fix the lines in pandas yourself or wait for pandas 0.15.1

Comment: My PandasSQLAlchemy broke at the same time - do you have any thoughts on that?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593344/sqlalchemy-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-pandassqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try: pip install pandas (btw, you should install pip first).