# SQLAlchemy AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PandasSQLAlchemy'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a pandas Dataframe to a Postgres database:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
engine = create_engine(r'postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/db')
meta = MetaData(engine, schema='data_quality')
meta.reflect(engine, schema='data_quality')
pdsql = pd.io.sql.PandasSQLAlchemy(engine, meta=meta)
pdsql.to_sql(dataframe, table_name)
```

It was working perfectly, but now SQLAlchemy is throwing the following error at the 5th line:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PandasSQLAlchemy'
```

I'm not sure if it's related, but Pandas broke at the same time - exactly like in this google-api-python-client issue:

[Could not Import Pandas: TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481285/could-not-import-pandas-)

I installed the google-api-python-client yesterday and uninstalling it fixed the problem with Pandas, but SQLAlchemy still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using pandas 0.15. `PandasSQLAlchemy` was not yet really public, and was renamed in pandas 0.15 to `SQLDatabase`. So if you replace that in your code, it should work (so `pdsql = pd.io.sql.SQLDatabase(engine, meta=meta)`).

However, starting from pandas 0.15, there is also schema support in the `read_sql_table` and `to_sql` functions, so it should not be needed to make a `MetaData` and `SQLDatabase` object manually. Instead, this should do it:

```
dataframe.to_sql(table_name, engine, schema='data_quality')
```

See the 0.15 release notes: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#improvements-in-the-sql-io-module

Comment: (Didn't realise that I updated to Pandas 0.15 when I was fixing the pandas import error earlier)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this error recently and it was solved my removing the .pyc files located in the same directory as .py files. These files (.pyc) holds the previous version information and time, date.