# AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute 'engine'

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am using Pandas to get data from a Microsoft SQL Server.
I use `read_sql_query` and I don't understand why I have the following error:

```
in read_sql_query
    pandas_sql = pandasSQL_builder(con)
in pandasSQL_builder
    if _is_sqlalchemy_connectable(con):
in _is_sqlalchemy_connectable
    return isinstance(con, sqlalchemy.engine.Connectable)
```

> ```
> AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute 'engine'
> ```

I use Python 3.6
My version of Pandas is 0.19.2
My version of sqlalchemy is 1.1.15

Comment: Similar question is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593344/sqlalchemy-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-pandassqlalchemy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593344/sqlalchemy-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-pandassqlalchemy)