# flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "flaskr.flaskr"

Tags: python, flask

I'm working through: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/

I've written `__init__.py` (code here: http://codepad.org/4FGIE901) in a /flaskr/ directory, set up a virtual environment called 'venv' and installed Flask.

I then ran these commands — on the command line, in the flaskr directory – as 'Run the application' advises: (`export FLASK_APP=flaskr`, `export FLASK_ENV=development`, `flask run`)

What I should see is `Hello, World!`

Instead, I'm presented with the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/David/Desktop/flaskr/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 330, in __call__
    rv = self._load_unlocked()

  File "/Users/David/Desktop/flaskr/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 317, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()

  File "/Users/David/Desktop/flaskr/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 372, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)

  File "/Users/David/Desktop/flaskr/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 246, in locate_app
    'Could not import "{name}".'.format(name=module_name)

flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "flaskr.flaskr".
```

Simply, I'm not sure how I should respond to or work upon fixing an error like this. Perhaps I have a mismatch in what I have installed in the venv and what this particular project requires?

Like this person: [Could not Import Pandas: TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481285/could-not-import-pandas-typeerror)

Flask:

- `/Users/David/Desktop/flaskr/venv/bin/Flask`
- Version: 1.0.2

Pip:

- `from /Users/David/Desktop/flaskr/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`
- Version: 9.0.1

Python:

- `/Users/David/Desktop/flaskr/venv/bin/python`
- Version: 3.6.0

Comment: Is your cwd the same as where flaskr is stored?

Comment: I believe so, yes. Typing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10783138/9214153 on terminal, within my virtualenv for flaskr offers: `'/Users/David/Desktop/flaskr`

Answer (score 95):

I think you are in the wrong folder. You probably did:

```
cd flask_tutorial/flaskr
```

You need to go up to the tutorial folder:

```
cd ..
```

You should `flask run` in the `flask_tutorial` folder rather than `flask_tutorial/flaskr` because you want to import `flaskr` from that folder, not `flaskr/flaskr` (which doesn't exist).

Comment: You're absolutely right and this has solved the issue. I was trying to run the app from within the flaskr directory rather than with the flask_tutorial directory. Many, many thanks :)

Comment: When I opened my project in VScode I opened the folder with the project and the file _init_. Thank you for the help @DavidGodwin, it took a while to figure out why it was not working my ``` flask run```

Answer (score 3):

> Those running flask for the first time ..This works well for windows

find the location of your folder use cmd please 'mine is cd /users/hp/Desktop'

`cd /users/hp/Desktop>set FLASK_APP=hello.py   -->file name 
cd /users/hp/Desktop>set FLASK_ENV=development
cd /users/hp/Desktop>flask run`

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the latest versions of `Flask` and `Werkzeug` and everything was fixed:

```
python -m pip install Flask==2.0.1
python -m pip install Werkzeug==2.0.1
```

**Notes:**

1. I did not use `__init__.py`
2. I run flask app as:

```
set FLASK_ENV=development
set FLASK_APP=app.py
flask run --port 5000
```