# flask.cli.NoAppException [flaskr tutorial]

Tags: python, flask

Wow, so I feel incredibly silly for posing this question, but what am I doing wrong?

When accessing the server (http://127.0.0.1:5000/), I repeatedly get the error:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "flaskr.flaskr".

pwd: ./flask/flaskr
```

Then I researched the error and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574293/flask-cli-noappexception-could-not-import-flaskr-flaskr?noredirect=1&lq=1) to be most relevant to my problem, but I [cd ..] to pwd [./flask] but received a 404 error.  This has been plaguing me all day and I would greatly appreciate aid!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow to all the steps described in [readme](https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/tutorial) ?

Especially: `pip install -e .`

Comment: Thank you, but I was aiming to follow along with the tutorial step-by-step as opposed to downloading the entire completed project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. What I did was to create a folder named `flaskr` and then move the `__init__.py` file into it (that is move the `__init__.py` into `flaskr` folder).